# Api version change but docs not updated?

Tags: ms-office, preview, office365

I've been trying to do various things through your Mail REST API today and not having much success... My project (using the api) has been running for at least a month now, but requests to your api are failing.

For example:
GET https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/messages (works)
GET https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/inbox (doesn't work)
Looking at the documentation, still says its available.

Trying to send an email using:
POST https://outlook.office365.com/EWS/OData/Me/Messages?MessageDisposition=SendAndSaveCopy also just returns 400 (Bad Request)

Any info about this?

Also, the http status codes returned are not useful at all; almost all errors return as 400's. In one instance, I didn't provide auth creds, and a 400 was returned instead of the appropriate 401. The accompanying status code detail could also be more helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback and sorry for the inconvenience.  We are currently deploying some non-backwards compatible changes described [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6fc135ae-f8f9-4b4d-b50b-f00a2bd79a30/office-365-rest-api-mail-calendar-contacts-update?forum=exchangesvrdevelopment), and this is causing your issues.  The current set of changes including versioning support, and deploying non-backwards compatible changes won't cause issues for your app in the future.  For the queries, that don't work, please use the following:

1. Accessing Inbox: https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/me/folders/inbox
2. Send email (new action called SendMail):

POST https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/me/sendmail

```
{
  "Message":
  {
    "Subject": "Test message",
    "Body":
    {
      "Content": "This is test message!"
    },
    "ToRecipients":
    [
       { "EmailAddress": { "Address": "John@contoso.com", "Name": "John Doe"  }},
       { "EmailAddress": { "Address": "Jane@fabrikam.com", "Name": "Jane Smith"  }} 
    ]
  },
  "SaveToSentItems": true
}
```

Hope this helps.  We are updating the documentation to reflect the changes, and it should be available shortly.  Thanks for the feedback on the HTTP status codes, we will review the status codes returned currently and make any fixes required.

Conversation support is in our roadmap but we don't yet have a timeline to share.  Currently, you can search using https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Folders/FolderId/Messages?$filter=ConversationId%20eq%20%%27ConversationID%27 but this will only return messages within the specified folder belonging to that conversation.

Let me know if you have any questions or need more info.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: Sorry Venkat, just a quick question: Getting messages by the conversationId, will that be exposed in a near future release? I have requirement for it and I'm hoping that's another feature that will be released soon.

Comment: Hi Gavin, I updated my answer to include info on conversation support. Let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Venkat, I haven't tried the conversation filter yet, but from what you've said, I think that will work just perfectly.. Many thanks